# How to use 'this' in Promise?

Tags: angular, typescript, post, httpclient, undefined

I am trying to make an http request inside a Promise function.
I get the `this.http.post` is `undefined error...`
I know that I somehow have to access `this` some other way but I did not understand how to do it.

Anyone willing to help me out?

```
doUpload(files: Array<File>): Promise<Array<UploadResult>> {
    console.log(files);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let result: Array<UploadResult> = [];
        for (let file of files) {
          this.http
            .post(this.APIURL + "/image/upload/markdown", file)
            .subscribe((data) => {
              console.log(data);
            });
          result.push({
            name: file.name,
            url: `https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/${file.name}`,
            isImg: file.type.indexOf("image") !== -1,
          });
        }
        resolve(result);
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

The error:

```
> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.http.post')  
> (anonyme Funktion) — sensor-edit.component.ts:308  
> onInvokeTask — core.js:39680  
> runTask — zone-evergreen.js:168  
> invokeTask — zone-evergreen.js:465  
> timer — zone-evergreen.js:2650
```

The constructor:

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private api: ApiService,
    private _routerService: Router,
    private errorService: ErrorModalService,
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}
```

And `doUpload` is called in my Html like this:

```
<div class="container well come-space">
          <md-editor formControlName="markdown" name="Content" [height]="'400px'" [upload]="doUpload">
          </md-editor>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the error stack? Arrow function will automatically point to the correct lexical scope. It should work fine.

Comment: In addition, log `this.http`. It seems it points to some object, but not to the one you expect.

Comment: Sure. Just edited the question. When I log `this.http` it says `undefined`..

Comment: Please show us the `constructor` of your component as well as the module declaration where this component is being declared in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Also, [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where `doUpload` is called ?

Comment: Wow, the way you pass `doUpload` is weird. You actually pass the function as an input ? Can you try to pass `doUpload.bind(this)` instead ? (make an intermediate variable in the ts if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I don't see the use of converting the Observable to Promise here. In fact at the moment you're creating multiple subscriptions that could be left open. Instead I'd use the RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) to trigger multiple observables in parallel within a single subscription.

Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

doUpload(files: Array<File>): Observable<Array<UploadResult>> {
  return forkJoin(                                  // <-- RxJS `forkJoin` function
    files.map((file: any) =>                        // <-- `Array#map` function
      this.http.post(
        this.APIURL + "/image/upload/markdown", 
        file
      ).pipe(
        map((data: any) => ({                       // <-- RxJS `map` operator
          name: file.name,
          url: `https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/${file.name}`,
          isImg: file.type.indexOf("image") !== -1,
        }))
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Then you could subscribe to it

```js
this.doUpload(files).subscribe({
  next: (response) => console.log(response),
  error: (error) => console.log(error)
});
```

#### Update

As told in the comments, my solution cannot be used in combination with `<md-editor>`'s `@Input() upload` variable. Use your own `doUpload()` implementation with the following snippet your component's constructor.

```js
constructor() {
  this.doUpload = this.doUpload.bind(this);
}
```

Taken from [`ngx-markdown-editor`'s docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown-editor).

Comment: While your answer holds a true statement, it does not answer the actual question.

Comment: Thanks.. but now I get this error `undefined is not a function (near '...files.map...')`

Comment: I didn't realize you were passing the `doUpload()` function as an `@Input` to the `<md-editor>`. In this case my solution wouldn't apply. Try doing `this.doUpload = this.doUpload.bind(this);` inside the component's constructor with your initial implementation of the `doUpload()` function. Taken from their [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-markdown-editor).